# Limpiar/reemplazar palabras de archivo json python

Tags: python

Tengo este código:

```
def reemplazar(o_text):
for k, v in replace_words.items():  #probe con iteritems tambien pero no va
    e_text = o_text.replace(k, v)
return e_text
```

La idea es, recibir desde un diccionario las palabras a sustituir en el string que recibo en la función, y sustituya todas las palabras que contiene.

```
replace: {
   "Hola": "Hello", 
   "Mundo" : "World",
   "Prueba" : "Probe", 
}
```

Aquí viene el problema, la función solo reemplaza la ultima palabra que defino en el diccionario. Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal para que no compruebe todas las palabras con las palabras del diccionario?

Y mi otra pregunta es, como puedo hacer para que la funcion o el diccionario incluya la sustitución u omisión de comillas: """" ?

Esto lo pregunto porque el string que recibo tiene el formato de un json.

```
{
  "Dia": "Martes",
  "Fecha": "4-2-2019"
}
```

Para que quedara de esta forma:

```
Dia: Martes
Fecha: 4-2-2019
```

Muchas gracias por su atención.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que ocurre es que siempre estás reemplazando sobre la cadena de entrada (`o_text`) que permanece inmutable ya que no la vuelves a asignar. Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
def reemplazar(o_text):
    e_text = o_text
    for k, v in replace_words.items():  #probe con iteritems tambien pero no va
        e_text = e_text.replace(k, v)
    return e_text
```

En cuanto a que tienes el diccionario en un formato `json`, si lo lees usando alguna de las rutinas básicas para interpretar un `json` no deberías tener ningún tipo de problema. Conceptualmente cualquier objeto, que sea serializable como un diccionario, si lo salvas como `json` a un archivo y lo vuelves a leer (usando las rutinas adecuadas) deberías obtener el mismo objeto original.

Ejemplo:

```
import json

js = """{
   "Hola": "Hello", 
   "Mundo" : "World",
   "Prueba" : "Probe"
}"""

replace_words = json.loads(js)
print(replace_words)

{'Hola': 'Hello', 'Mundo': 'World', 'Prueba': 'Probe'}
```

Comment: Estaba tan occecado que no me di cuenta del fallo...que tonto... Y respecto al json, es un string plano "{...data...}" que yo recibo por programa con lo cual no necesito cargar el json, lo mencione por hacer referencia al formato de texto. Muchas gracias igualmente por la explicación y ejemplo. Ha quedado funcional 100%